# Problem in plotting support vector contours in Jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, contour

I am following [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-separating-hyperplane-py) script from ScikitLearn to plot the margins and the hyperplane for SVC. I'm executing each line in a different cell and am following the same order, i.e. cell 1 for line 1, cell 2 for line 2, and so on. When I finally get to the plotting part, say on cell k(which is the last cell in my notebook that holds the last 7 lines of the code), I get `UserWarning: No contour levels were found within the data range.` and no plot as mentioned in the link given above shows up.

However, when I execute all the lines in the same cell, the code works as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs


# we create 40 separable points
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=40, centers=2, random_state=6)

# fit the model, don't regularize for illustration purposes
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1000)
clf.fit(X, y)

plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=30, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)

# plot the decision function
ax = plt.gca()
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
ylim = ax.get_ylim()

# create grid to evaluate model
xx = np.linspace(xlim[0], xlim[1], 30)
yy = np.linspace(ylim[0], ylim[1], 30)
YY, XX = np.meshgrid(yy, xx)
xy = np.vstack([XX.ravel(), YY.ravel()]).T
Z = clf.decision_function(xy).reshape(XX.shape)

# plot decision boundary and margins
ax.contour(XX, YY, Z, colors='k', levels=[-1, 0, 1], alpha=0.5,
           linestyles=['--', '-', '--'])
# plot support vectors
ax.scatter(clf.support_vectors_[:, 0], clf.support_vectors_[:, 1], s=100,
           linewidth=1, facecolors='none', edgecolors='k')
plt.show()
```

Comment: in general you want all of your plotting commands in the same cell. so do it that way. if you want to explore each line granularly, comment them out.

Comment: Also which cell is cell k? you need to be specific about where your errors originate

Comment: I'm trying to break that code to bits and pieces to understand what each line does, cell k just represents the last cell in my notebook, which would contain the last 7 lines of the code

Comment: are you using an interactive backend? with `%matplotlib notebook`, breaking this up works fine for me. You should be specific in your question (use the edit button) about where "cell k" starts and stops

Comment: I was using `%matplotlib inline` but that didn't work. I've edited the question as per your instructions. `%matplotlib notebook` works fine but I don't really want a single dynamic plot there. I want each cell to have its own ouptut. Isn't there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do, without using magic functions?

Comment: if you don't want to use an interactive backend, each cell has to built its own plot from scratch. If you want to granularly explore this this plot, comment out lines strategically and rerun the same cell repeatedly.

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail? I didn't get the "commenting out strategically" part

Comment: put a `#` in front of the lines you don't want executed

Comment: or use an interactive backend. if you're learning about this code, there's no harm in it.

Comment: Yes, I know how comments work, but isn't there any other way than commenting lines out? I'm not so sure about the interactive backend as I might have to convert this notebook to pdf with a description of the code

Comment: you can convert to PDF and still see the plot with the `notebook` interactive backend. i feel like you need to tinker around with this a little more. all of these road blocks feel artificial.

Comment: I think so too but I thought there may be some quick workaround

Comment: the quick work around is the `notebook` backend, which has not impact at on your ability to export the notebook